# Как использовать обученную модель нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Добрый день!

Не могу понять, как использовать уже обученную модель нейронной сети. 
Программирую на питоне, использую библиотеку keras. Анализирую временные ряды. Нейронная сеть обучена, модель сохранена.

Как описано в документации keras, надо вызвать метод model_name.predict().
Хорошо. Делаю так: model.predict(dataset), где dataset - это значения за последние 90 дней. А мне надо получить прогноз вперед на, скажем, 10 дней.

Но прогноз делается только для указанного набора данных на 90 дней! То есть можно только сравнить исходные данные и прогнозные. Практического толка никакого.

Так как же делать прогноз наперед?

Comment: Вам надо скормить модели входные данные за __следующие__ 10 дней. Данные должны быть в нужном формате (такой же как у вашего `dataset`)

Comment: MaxU, вы меня не поняли. Стоит задача именно предсказать значения на 10 дней вперед. Сегодня 24 января, мне нужен прогноз по 3 февраля. А метод predict( ), в том то и проблема, можно использовать только при наличии входных данных. Вот как сделать так, чтобы я передал в обученную модель сети данные за последние 90 дней, включая сегодняшний, а она мне предсказала значения на 10 дней с завтрашнего дня?

Comment: Как выглядит ваш `dataset`? Из чего он состоит?

Comment: Это интервальный временной ряд в формате csv. Количество посетителей сайта по дням. Одна колонка, ничего больше. Ряд, конечно, преобразуется к виду [datasetX, datasetY] за счет дублирования массива и смещения его на одно значение вверх

Comment: ну тогда вам просто надо указать время (следующие 10 дней) в качестве входных данных в таком же формате, в каком модель обучалась

Comment: Вот хотелось бы разобраться, как это делать. К сожалению, не нашел информации. Вот как задается функция: predict(self, x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None). Как видим, можно подать только один набор данных - значение х. Это те самые 90 дней. 10 дней уже впихнуть некуда ((

Comment: по-моему данные за прошедшие 90 дней нужны были только для обучения модели. Для предсказания они не нужны..

Comment: Модель обучается на других данных. Предположим, что у меня есть набор из 300 значений. Первые 210 используются для обучения. Из них формируется обучающая и тестовая выборки. А вот для предсказания я беру последние 90 значений. Как бы говорю уже обученной модели сети, что вот тебе 90 последних значений, дай мне прогноз на 10 значений. Как-то так

Comment: я врядли смогу помочь не имея ваших данных и обученной модели...

Comment: MaxU, в любом случае спасибо )  Я вчера наткнулся на пример кода, который вроде реализует то, что я хочу. Посмотрим, что он выдает, а там видно будет ))

Comment: Артур, вы не могли бы поделиться этим примером кода? Столкнулся с той же проблемой, но решения не нахожу.

Comment: Я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой, может кто помочь подсказать или дать ссылку на код?